# Find likelihood function and MLE for hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling, maximum-likelihood, descriptive-statistics

I'm currently reading about statistics and I'm trying to understand likelihood function and MLE (maximum likelihood estimation).

I have come across an exercise which is basically like this:

I'm given four numbers including $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $n$, where $n$ is the total number of trials. The numbers for $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are all different.

Then I'm given a model $M_0$ which states that $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is distributed as the multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)$ where $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3) \in \Pi^3$.

Finally, I have to consider the hypothesis $H_1: (\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3) = (1 - 2p, p, p)$, $p \in (0, 0.5)$

My task is then to show that the likelihood function for the hypothesis $H_1$ is given by:

$$
L(p) ={{n} \choose {x_1,x_2,x_3}}\cdot (1 - 2p)^{x_1}\cdot p^{x_2+x_3}
$$

and show that the maximum likelihood estimation for p is given by

$$
\hat{p} = \frac{x_2 +x_3}{2n}.
$$

I have been reading and watching a lot of videos about the likelihood function and MLE in order to try to understand it, but I don't even know where to begin in this case. Also, I'm a bit confused whether $p \in (0, 0.5)$ means that $p$ is either $0$ or $0.5$ since the brackets used aren't the normal set brackets { and }.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have interpretated $(n,x_1, x_2, x_3)$ as a trinomial coefficient. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, your edit to my post is totally correct. I didn't know how to put n and x1, x2, x3 on separate lines. Thank you

Comment: $p \in (0, 0.5)$ means that $p$ is between $0$ and $0.5$ (exclusive). If $p>0.5$ then $1-2p$ is negative.

Comment: Thank you. Why didn't the author of the task use the interval brackets [ and ]? Normally I wouldn't associate ( and ) with interval

Comment: There are two kinds of interval brackets $(a,b )$ and $[a,b]$. The latter one is inclusive. The brackets for elements is $x\in \{a,b \}$. It means that $x$ can be $a$ or $b$, but not between $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for a multinomial distribution the PDF is

$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_k; n, \pi_1, \ldots, \pi_k) = \frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}\pi^{x_1} \cdots \pi^{x_k} = {{n} \choose {x_1,\ldots,x_k}}\pi^{x_1} \cdots \pi^{x_k}
$$

with

$$
\sum_{i= 1}^k x_i = n
$$

In your case $k = 3$. The likelihood evaluated at the point ${\bf p} = (1 - 2p, p, p)$ is then

$$
L({\bf p}) = {{n} \choose {x_1,x_2,x_3}}(1- 2p)^{x_1} p^{x_2} p^{x_3} = {{n} \choose {x_1,x_2,x_3}}(1- 2p)^{x_1} p^{x_2+ x_3} = L(p)
$$

Now, to find the value of $p$ for which $L(p)$ we need to solve $dL/dp = 0$

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dL}{dp} &=& (1-2 p)^{x_1} (x_2 + x_3) p^{x_2 + x_3-1}-2
   x_1 (1-2 p)^{x_1-1} p^{x_2 + x_3} \\
&=& (1 - 2p)^{x_1}p^{x_2 + x_3} \left(\frac{x_2 + x_3}{p} - 2\frac{x_1}{1 - 2p} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore the value of $\hat{p}$ for which $dL(\hat{p})/dp = 0$ is

$$
\frac{x_2 + x_3}{\hat{p}} - 2\frac{x_1}{1 - 2\hat{p}} = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow ~~~ \hat{p} = \frac{x_2 + x_3}{2(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)}
$$

or equivalently

$$
\hat{p} = \frac{x_2 + x_3}{2n}
$$

Comment: In the last part of your L(p) formula, it should be p^x2+x3 instead of p^x1+x2, right? Anyways, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @JamesH Right, just a typo

Comment: The solution should be $\hat{p} = \frac{x_2 + x_3}{2n}$. I think your first order condition is right, but the solution is not.

Comment: @callculus You're absolutely right, I messed up in the last step. Already fixed it. Thanks

Comment: You assume here that the solution of the likelihood equation is the MLE. In this case you can quickly show that it is, but you haven't included that.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $p\in(a,b)$ means $a<p<b$, and $p\in[a,b]$ means $a\le p \le b$, and $p\in(a,b]$ means $a<p\le b$ and $p\in[a,b)$ means $a\le p<b.$ The notation $p\in\{a,b\},$ on the other hand, means either $p=a$ or $p=b.$

You have
$$
L(p) ={n \choose x_1,x_2,x_3} (1 - 2p)^{x_1}\cdot p^{x_2+x_3}.
$$
Thus
$$
\ell(p) = \log L(p) = \text{constant} + x_1 \log(1-2p) + (x_2+x_3)\log p.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\ell\,'(p) & = \frac{-2x_1}{1-2p} + \frac{x_1+x_2} p \\[10pt] & = \frac{(x_2+x_3) -2p(x_1+x_2+x_3)}{p(1-2p)} \quad \begin{cases} > 0 & \text{if } 0<p<\dfrac{x_2+x_3}{2(x_1+x_2+x_3)}, \\[10pt] < 0 & \text{if } \dfrac{x_2+x_3}{2(x_1+x_2+x_3)} < p < 1. \end{cases}
\end{align}

The problem ought to have said $p\in[0,1/2]$ rather than $p\in(0,1/2).$ The probability of an endpoint maximum is clearly more than $0$ and the MLE would be at an endpoint in that case.